# How to get Total of Column in DataGridView in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I used the below code and it's rounding the result

```
Dim iTax As Double

If VacationsDataGridView.RowCount > 1 Then
    For index As Double = 0 To VacationsDataGridView.RowCount - 1
        iTax += Convert.ToDouble(VacationsDataGridView.Rows(index).Cells(3).Value)
    Next

    Label4.Text = iTax
End If
```

I don't know what's the mistake!

Comment: If the cells contain `Double` values, why would you convert them to `Strings` and then back to `Doubles`? Don't convert things to `Strings` unless you need `Strings`. If the data is type `Double` then cast it as that type.

Comment: I removed the string but still the same problem

Comment: If the question no longer accurately reflects your issue then please edit the question.

Comment: Could you confirm VacationsDataGridView.Rows(index).Cells(3) is a Double too please

Comment: I did. I modified the Code above but Still the same problem.This code in in a Radiobutton Checked Changed and when I select another radiobutton with the same code it reflects a wrong result